# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error in connection to oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle

```
string oradb ="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = " +
            "(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL =TCP)(HOST="+HostName+")(PORT=XXXX))" +
            "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
            "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
            "(SERVICE_NAME = "serviceName"))" +
            ");Persist Security Info=True;User ID="userID";Password=
<Password>;
        try{
            conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
            conn.Open();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Report.Warn("DB Connection not opened, Please check once, 
exception message: "+e.Message);
        }
```

Getting an error when trying to connect oracle DB and execute query.

Tried with many other options but no use..

Comment: Does it catch the exception ? Or it doesn't fail at conn.Open() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Got fixed by installing Oracle client , as it was not there in my machine , i faced this issue ..

Comment: Congragulations!!

Answer (score 0):

For me below was the solution :
Installing Oracle Database Instant Client on Windows
To Install Oracle Instant Client on Windows:

Create an installation directory for the Oracle R Enterprise client components. For example:

c:\oreclient_install_dir
Go to the Oracle Database Instant Client page on the Oracle Technology Network.

Select See Instant Client downloads for all platforms.

On the Instant Client Downloads page, select Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (x64).

On the Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) page, accept the license agreement.

Choose Instant Client Package - Basic for your version of Oracle Database.

Save the file in the installation directory that you created in Step 1. For example:

c:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
Unzip the file. The files are extracted into a subdirectory called instantclient_version, where version is your version of Oracle Database. For example:

c:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_12_1
Return to the Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) page.

Accept the license agreement and select Instant Client Package - SDK for your version of Oracle Database.

Save the file in the installation directory that you created in Step 1.

c:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
Unzip the file. The files are extracted into the instantclient_version subdirectory.

Add the full path of the Instant Client to the environment variables OCI_LIB64 and PATH. The following steps set the variables to the path used in this example, c:\myoreclient\instantclient_12_1:

In Windows Control Panel, choose System, then click Advanced system settings.

On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.

Under System variables, create OCI_LIB64 if it does not already exist. Set the value of OCI_LIB64 to c:\oreclient\instantclient_12_1.

Under System variables, edit PATH to include c:\oreclient\instantclient_12_1.

for more information visit : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.html#GUID-A0AAF57E-D74F-43F1-BD92-81D197EFE17F